# Run bash script in WSL through powershell script

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to run a script which launches a WSL (ubuntu1804) terminal, and then run a bash script in that terminal

```
.\ubuntu1804.exe;
cd test_directory;
node server.js;
```

However after the first command the terminal open however, the two other commands aren't executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.\ubuntu1804.exe` by itself opens an *interactive* shell which PowerShell executes *synchronously*.

That is, until you submit `exit` in that interactive shell to terminate it, control won't be returned to PowerShell, so the subsequent commands - `cd test_directory` and `note server.js` - are not only not sent to `.\ubuntu1804.exe`, as you intended, but are then run *by PowerShell*.

Instead, you must pass the commands to run to `.\ubuntu1804.exe` via the `run` sub-command:

```
.\ubuntu1804.exe run 'cd test_directory; node server.js'
```

Note: Once `node` exits, control will be returned to PowerShell.