# How to run a bash script on wsl with powershell?

Tags: bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

On my current directory on Windows, I have the following script file simple_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi from simple script"
```

I wish to run this script on wsl via the powershell command line.

Using the `wsl` command, I could not find a way to tell wsl to invoke the script code.

The following command works (I think)

```
wsl bash -c "echo hi from simple script"
```

However when trying to load the script content into a variable and running it does not work as expected:

```
$simple_script = Get-Content ./simple_script.sh
wsl bash -c $simple_script
```

Fails with:

```
bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

I tried a few variants. using `Get-Content` with the `-Raw` flag seems to make the first word in the string to print (but not the whole string). commands that don't contain '"' characters seems to work sometimes. But I haven't found a consistent way.

[A similar looking question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587559/run-bash-script-in-wsl-through-powershell-script) doesn't seem to work directly with the wsl, and doesn't seem to run a script file that resides on the Windows file system.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The robust and efficient way to **execute your shebang-line-based shell script from Windows** is **via `wsl.exe -e`**

```bash
wsl -e ./simple_script.sh # !! ./ is required
```

Note:

- Without `./` to explicitly indicate that the executable is located in the current directory, the command would fail *quietly* (only executables located in directories listed in the `PATH` environment variable can be invoked *by name only*).
- `-e` *bypasses* involvement of a shell on the Linux side, and instead lets a Linux system function interpret the shebang-line-based plain-text file, which automatically honors the specified interpreter.

  - *Important*: If you get `ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe ./t.sh failed 8`,<sup>[1]</sup> the implication is that your `.sh` file is either lacking a shebang line or its shebang line is malformed; be sure that your file starts with a line like `#!/bin/bash` at the *very start* of the file, and that the file is UTF-8-encoded *without a BOM* and uses *Unix-format LF-only newlines*.
    If your script lacks a shebang line and you cannot/don't want to add one, but you know what shell it was written for, invoke it via that shell's executable, e.g.
    `wsl -e bash ./simple_script.sh`
- Perhaps surprisingly, WSL considers *all* files located in the *Windows* file-system, including plain-text ones, to have the *executable bit* set, which you can easily verify with `wsl -e ls -l ./simple_script.sh`

---

As for **what you tried**:

```bash
# !! WRONG
$simple_script = Get-Content ./simple_script.sh
wsl bash -c $simple_script
```

The primary problem is that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) by default returns an *array* of lines, and attempting to use that array as an argument to an *external program* such as `wsl` causes the array's elements to be passed *as individual arguments*.

The **immediate fix is to use the `-Raw` switch**, which makes `Get-Content` return the file content as a *single, multi-line string*.

However, **due to a highly unfortunate, long-standing bug, PowerShell - up to v7.2.x - requires *manual* `\`-*escaping* of *embedded `"` characters* in arguments passed to external programs**.

- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for details.

Therefore:

```bash
# Using -Raw, read the file in full, as a single, multi-line string.
$simple_script = Get-Content -Raw ./simple_script.sh

# !! The \-escaping is needed up to PowerShell 7.2.x
wsl bash -c ($simple_script -replace '"', '\"')
```

Note that while it is **tempting to try to bypass the need to escape by providing the script text *via the pipeline* (stdin)**, this **does *not* work as expected, as of PowerShell 7.3.3**:

```bash
# !! Tempting, but does NOT work.
Get-Content -Raw ./simple_script.sh | wsl -e bash
```

The reason this doesn't work is that **PowerShell invariably appends a *Windows-format* newline (CRLF) to what is being sent to external programs via the pipeline**, which Bash doesn't recognize.

- This problematic behavior is being discussed in [GitHub issue #13579](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13579).

---

<sup>[1] System error `8` is `ENOEXEC`, the *Exec format error*, indicating that while the target file has the appropriate permissions for being executed, its format isn't recognized. This could be due to file corruption, being an executable for the wrong platform or - in the case at hand - due to being a text file that lacks a well-formed shebang line.</sup>

Comment: Brooo!!!!!!!!!!! You are a legend for this. If you ever need something I can give you just know... IOU 1

Comment: This is awesome. Is there any way to retrieve the output of the shell script once it completes? I have a script that outputs a series of HTML color HEX codes that I need to use further on in my PowerShell script.

Comment: Also, is there a way to pass arguments to the shell script in this way? I need to pass an image file to the script.

Comment: @fmotion1, just append the arguments to the command line. Capturing output works as with any command in PowerShell, e.g., `$output = wsl -e ./simple_script.sh arg1 arg2`, though note that this only covers success-stream / stdout output. To capture stderr output too use a `2>` redirection.

Comment: I tried this recently, and the `-e` flag needs a shell specified to run properly. i.e.
`wsl -e bash ./simple_script.sh` Otherwise I  would get 

`<3>WSL (7606) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:502: execvpe ./simple_script.sh failed 8`

`<3>WSL (7606) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:505: Create process not expected to return`

Comment: @A.Penner, that implies that your `.sh` is either lacking a shebang line or its shebang line is malformed. In that case you must indeed specify the shell executable explicitly. I've updated the answer to clarify that.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, it turns out the Windows line ending were enough to mangle my line endings. Once corrected, it worked exactly as you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble getting the above steps to work for me. It turned out to be an issue with the default Linux distribution in WSL. These steps resolved it.

Step 1: Check current distros

```
❯ wsl --list
Windows Subsystem for Linux Distributions:
docker-desktop-data (Default)
Ubuntu
docker-desktop
```

That `docker-desktop-data` default seemed to be the problem.

Step 2: Change the default

`> wsl --setdefault Ubuntu`

After that everything started working.

**See also**
[How to set default distro using WSL2 on Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/set-default-distro-wsl2-windows-10/)

Comment: Ah, it was the `docker-desktop-data` problem again.  In that case, I'd also encourage you to vote for [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8727) and/or the (Microsoft) proposed solution in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8727#issuecomment-1218365160).  I'd love to see this implemented so that folks don't run into this particular problem in the future.

Comment: Also note that you can run the script in *any* installed distribution (whether or not it is the default) using `wsl -d Ubuntu -e ./script.sh` (substituting the actual distribution name for `Ubuntu` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To run the script on `wsl` you simply invoke `bash`

```
> bash simple_script.sh
hi from simple script
```

To save it in a variable and have it run as a `bash` script within `wsl` or `powershell`, there is no need for `Get-Content`

```
> $simple_script = bash /mnt/c/Users/user-name/path/to/simple_script.sh
> Write-Output $simple_script
hi from simple script
```

**NOTE:** Powershell has an alias mapping `echo` to `Write-Output`, so you could also use `echo`

```
> $simple_script = bash /mnt/c/Users/user-name/path/to/simple_script.sh
> echo $simple_script
hi from simple script
```

You can also grab the content if that was your initial aim.

```
> Get-Content simple_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi from simple script"
 
> $content = Get-Content .\simple_script.sh
> Write-Output $content
#!/bin/bash
echo "hi from simple script"
```

Comment: My mistake was trying `bash ./simple_script.sh` instead of just `bash simple_script.sh`. This is confusing.

Comment: As a heads-up, the `bash` command is deprecated in WSL.  It is recommended to use the `wsl` command instead - It's far more flexible.

Comment: @EladMaimoni, `bash ./simple_script.sh` works too, and is actually preferable, because, unlike `bash simple_script.sh`, it doesn't fall back to looking for a `simple_script.sh` script _in the `PATH`_ if it isn't in the current dir. However, you generally shouldn't pass a shell script with a shebang line to a specific shell for direct execution, unless you're sure that the same shell is also the one designated in the shebang line. In short: use `wsl -e ./simple_script.sh` instead.