# How do I get WSL Vim to accept pipeline input from Powershell?

Tags: powershell, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to create a Powershell function that acts as a wrapper for Vim in WSL. I would like this wrapper to be able to accept input from the pipeline.

In WSL, it's possible to do something like:

```
$ cat manylines.txt | vim -
```

The `-` indicates that Vim should read the input from stdin, which is then redirected through the pipeline. This will open vim with the command output already in the buffer, without any file associated.
(You could also simply open the file with `vim manylines.txt`, but that wouldn't work in general for the outputs of other commands or executables).

The same is possible in Powershell, with Windows native Vim:

```
Get-Content manylines.txt | vim -
```

It's possible to go one step further and execute Vim within another instance of Powershell or cmd:

```
Get-Content manylines.txt | powershell -Command vim -
Get-Content manylines.txt | cmd /c vim -
```

However, the same does not work with WSL Vim.

```
# doesn't work, Vim freezes
Get-Content manylines.txt | wsl vim -
Get-Content manylines.txt | wsl bash -c "vim -"

# doesn't work, Vim quits reporting "Error reading Input"
Get-Content manylines.txt | wsl bash -c vim -
```

In the first two cases, Vim opens correctly with the contents of manylines.txt in the buffer... and then refuses to accept any keyboard input. It is not possible to navigate, edit, or even quit with `:q!`.

Using a temporary powershell variable seems to fix things, but only when the input consists of a single line

```
# "works as long as the file only has a single line of text"
# "$tmpvar has type System.String (not an array)"
$tmpvar = Get-Content singleline.txt
wsl bash -c "echo $tmp | vim -"
```

But this breaks when $tmpvar becomes a String[] array or a String with any newlines

```
# sort of works, but newlines are converted to a single space
$tmpvar = [string[]] Get-Content manylines.txt
wsl bash -c "echo $tmp | vim -"

# combines the strings in the array, inserts a newline between each pair of elements
$tmpvar = ([string[]] Get-Content manylines.txt) -join "`n"
# doesn't work, bash interprets the newline as the start of the next command
wsl bash -c "echo $tmp | vim -"
```

How do I get WSL Vim to accept pipeline input from Powershell?

Other Notes:

- I could use a temporary file and pass the file to WSL Vim, but that's not an elegant solution and leaves a file that has to be cleaned up. Unless the temporary file is in the current directory, it also involves extra shenanigans with wslpath

Comment: Does `Get-Content .\manylines.txt -raw | wsl bash -c "vim -"` work?

Comment: @NicoNekoru Probably not, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72205311/11810933)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Hum.. it seems to be working fine on my end and `vim` should be able to parse `\r` but if that is the case then you should be able to resolve that with `(Get-Content .\manylines.txt -raw) -replace '\r','' | wsl bash -c "vim -"`

Comment: @NicoNekoru adding the `-raw` flag doesn't seem to make a difference - vim loads the contents correctly, but then freezes and doesn't take any more input. Removing '\r' doesn't seem to change much in this regard.

Comment: @NicoNekoru I'm surprised it's working for you - could you mention what wsl distro / shell you're using? (I'm on Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: @equatorialsnowfall I am on Ubuntu on WSL 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it seems that *piping* input to `vim` via `wsl` seems to break `vim`'s keyboard interface with respect to *cursor movements* (I was still able to type `:q!` to quit, for instance).

The workaround is to refine the approach you've discovered, namely to provide the input *as part of a shell command passed* to `wsl` instead of using the pipeline:

Doing so requires careful escaping and transformations, as shown in the following wrapper function:

```bash
# PowerShell wrapper function for invoking vim via WSL
function vim {
  if ($MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) { # pipeline input present
    $allInput = ($input | Out-String) -replace '\r?\n', "`n" -replace "'", "'\''" -replace '"', '\"'
    wsl -e sh -c "printf %s '$allInput' | vim $args -"
  }
  elseif ($args) { # no pipeline input, arguments that may include file paths given 
    wsl -e vim ($args.ToLower() -replace '^([a-z]):', '/mnt/$1' -replace '\\', '/')
  } else { # no pipeline input, no pass-through arguments
    wsl -e vim
  }
}
```

**Caveats:**

- When passing command output, you may run into the *max. command-line length*.
- When passing file paths, relative file paths work fine, but absolute ones work only for *local* drives (mapped drives / UNC paths require mounting a volume on the WSL side first).

With this function defined, you can call, say (`+`, as a sample option, tells `vim` to place the cursor at the end of the input):

```bash
vim + somefile.txt
```

or

```bash
Get-ChildItem | vim +
```

Comment: This seems to work rather well. It's not precisely vim conformant syntax, but that's an improvement (there's no need to add an extra '-' now). I wasn't able to find anything in the powershell about_* pages that indicates that $MyInvocation could be used this way. Do you happen to have any reference for this?

Comment: In the interest of completeness, I'd like to propose an addition to the code in the function: `$vimargs = $args | ForEach-Object {wsl wslpath "$_".replace('\','\\')}`, and then pass $vimargs to vim instead of $args. This ensures that Windows paths are understood, for example `vim $profile` would not work without it.

Comment: Good point about the path separators, but what you propose doesn't work for me. I'm still on WSL1 for technical reasons - don't know if that makes a difference - but I'm forced to translate something like `C:` into `/mnt/c` and replace all ``\`` with `/` - please see my update.