# Is there a way to run a bash shell script from WSL2 in PowerShell and both pass arguments and retrieve output from the script?

Tags: bash, powershell

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151630/how-to-run-a-bash-script-on-wsl-with-powershell) while researching this issue and I can get the script to run. But I have no idea how to pass arguments to my script (It's expecting 4 arguments).

I also need to capture its output as it emits a list of HEX color codes on completion.

Is this possible?

This is what I have:

```
# Using -Raw, read the file in full, as a single, multi-line string.
$DcolorsScript = Get-Content -Raw ./shellscripts/dcolors.sh

# !! The \-escaping is needed up to PowerShell 7.2.x
wsl bash -c ($DcolorsScript -replace '"', '\"')
```

Comment: Nestin different shells is seldom a good idea, as there are lots of IO issues. How about if you either use Bash or Powershell for the whole thing instead?

Comment: Yeah, I actually decided to re-code the whole function in Python. My intentions were a bit misguided. Sorry.