# Bash scripts not running on VS Code on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, visual-studio-code, terminal, scripting

I wrote a Bash script in VS Code and it is not running at all.

I began my script with `#!/bin/bash` of course. I saved the file and I tried to make it executable via terminal, however the `chmod +x` command was not recognized by the system. I worked my way around and I made the file executable by typing `"icacls (bashfilename).sh /grant Everyone:RX` which was successful, however when I ran the script via terminal...nothing! Not an error, not anything. It is just repeating the path.

I use the command `./(bashfilename).sh` and I am in the correct path.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You don't have bash installed on your Windows machine, and you especially don't have any kind of file path `/bin/bash`. Try writing a Powershell script instead.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use bash commands at a Windows command prompt, but the command prompt speaks a very different language. Do you have WSL2 installed? If so, does ["How to run a bash script on wsl with powershell?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151630/how-to-run-a-bash-script-on-wsl-with-powershell) solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. [Install WSL2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)  - If you go this route you'll want to [read this VS Code documentation about using VS Code with WSL 2](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/09/03/wsl2), especially important that you install the [WSL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl).
2. You could also just install GitBash, which is included when you install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/).  If you haven't installed Git on your windows machine, VS Code will prompt you to install it when you click on source control, then you will have both Git and Gitbash.

Gitbash may be the more direct rout, but I recommend learning to use a linux distro in WSL2.